# A triangle $OAB$ is right angled at $O;$squares $OALM$ and $OBPQ$ are constructed on the sides $OA$ and $OB$ externally

Tags: geometry, vectors

A triangle $OAB$ is right angled at $O;$squares $OALM$ and $OBPQ$ are constructed on the sides $OA$ and $OB$ externally.Show that the lines $AP$ and $BL$ intersect on the altitude through $'O'$.

---

This question is asked in the vector section of my book.I tried to solve but in vain.I dont know what is the proper way to prove this question.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the intersection of $AP$ and $BL$ be $O'$.

Draw square $ABXY$ external to side $AB$, connect $OX,OY$.

Draw perpendicular lines from $A$ to $BL$ and from $B$ to $AP$, let the intersection be $Z$ (i.e. essentially we just make triangle $ABZ$ that $AZ\perp BL$ and $BZ\perp AP$)

Now first since $\triangle ABL\cong \triangle AYO$ we have the angle between $OY$ and $BL$ is the same as the angle between $AB$ and $AY$, which is ninty degrees. Hence $OY\perp BL$. Similarly $OX\perp AP$ as well.

Now we have $OY\parallel AZ$ and $OX\parallel BZ$ and $AB\parallel XY$.  From here we have $\angle ZAB=\angle OYX$ and $\angle ZBA=\angle OXY$. Furthermore since $AB=XY$ we have $\triangle ZAB\cong \triangle OYX$.

From this we know $ZOYA$ is a parallelogram and $ZO\parallel AY$ and hence $ZO\perp AB$. Furthermore, since $O'$ is the intersection of two altitudes of triangle $ZAB$, we have $O'$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ZAB$. Hence line $ZO$ which is the other altitude must pass through $O'$. From here we know $OO'$ is on the same line as $ZO$ and is perpendicular to $AB$. QED.